# Show that there exists a differentiable funcion s.t $|f(x)|^5+f(x)+x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Trying to prove this:
Consider the geometric locus of the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation:$y^5+y+x=0$

$a.-$ Prove that there exists a differentiable funcion s.t $|f(x)|^5+f(x)+x=0$

I got that $x=-(y^5+y)$ , and by getting its first derivative I know that x must be a decreasing and injective function, so that its inverse does exist.
However now I don't know how to proceed, I know that somehow I have to use implicit differentiation but I don't know how to apply it to the problem.

$b:$ I have to get $f\prime$ in terms of $f$ using at least two methods.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the absolute values right?  That is, the $y^5+y+x=0$ is not the same as $|f(x)|^5 + f(x) + x = 0$.

Comment: I know is not the same, but still tying to figure out f(x) what can I do?

Comment: Should it be the geometric locus of $(x,y)$ satisfying $|y|^5+y+x=0$? That would make the question of a differentiable function $y=f(x)$ to satisfy it make sense.

Comment: No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

$$y^5+y+x = 0$$
Implicit differentiation gives
$$
(5y^4+1)\frac{dy}{dx} + 1 = 0\\ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{5y^4+1}$$

Since $5y^4+1$ is always greater than zero, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists (and is negative) everywhere.

By the above implicit differentiation, $$f(x)' = -\frac{1}{5f(x)^4+1} $$

Or we can do 
$$
x = -y^5-y\\
\frac{dx}{dy} = -4y^5-1 \\
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{\left( \frac{dx}{dy}  \right)} = -\frac{1}{5y^4+1}$$